# How to achieve this perfect soft gradient in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, gradient-mesh

This gradient looks subtle instead of a classic gradient bubble. Can you share a tip to recreate it in Illustrator?

[image: https://davidm147.deviantart.com/art/Soft-Blue-Gradient-203499364]

How to select start/middle/end colors and distances to recreate gradients?

Comment: How do you know that was created in Illustrator? Based upon the dithering in it, I suspect it was created using Photoshop or some raster-based application. Illustrator has no dithering options.

Comment: @Scott you could overlay a dither pattern though. ITS not as perfect but would still alleviate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I'm not saying it was created with Illustrator and I'm not talking about the anti-banding final touch, but about the underlining radial gradient.

Answer (score 0):

Achieve smooth and natural gradients like that by selecting the color value you'd like to use, then select a tint and a shade of that value to use for the gradient.

So just 2 colors, the tint at one end and the shade at the other. Put each one 5-10% in from the end so the end tones are pure.

This way one color appears to expand into lightness and darkness.

I suspect that your example has an additional radial gradient over it going from light to dark and set to multiply or another transparency setting, to enhance the light to darkness.